# Does the OpenGL GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT attribute bit denote Depth- and Stencil buffer related states?

Tags: opengl

I'm doing some work related to OpenGL 1.3 and ran into some uncertainties concerning some OpenGL state variables, and their relation to the attribute stack, in regards to their corresponding attribute bits. In the [OpenGL Super Bible](http://opengl.czweb.org/ch14/462-465.html) it is stated that the `GL_ENABLE_BIT` saves, amongst other variables, the `GL_DEPTH_TEST` and `GL_STENCIL_TEST` states.

However, the Bible also mentions that the `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` symbolic constant saves the 'current drawing buffer(s)', in addition to some less specific states. Instinctively, I feel as if the attribute bit should only constitute framebuffer (as in back-/color-buffer)-related states due to its name, but the depth- and stencil buffers are naturally buffers to which one may draw ('drawing buffers').

Similarly, the [Khronos man pages](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushAttrib.xml), while specifying many of the variables corresponding to respective bits, only briefly outline which states *some* of the bits denote (describing states such as 'Enable bits for the user-definable clipping planes').
My first thought was that this was due to the less-defined states (described in text rather than specifying `GLenum` names) being inaccessible to the user, and therefore not further detailed by Kronos.
Yet, there are multiple plain-text states that may be read from- and written to by the user which are not specified by name - such as 'Color mode and index mode clear values' (`GL_COLOR_CLEAR_VALUE`) and 'Color mode and index mode writemasks' (`GL_COLOR_WRITEMASK`) included under the `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` attribute bit - so this seems less likely.

While this may not pose any problems to the common user, it may be an issue to some developers (like myself, in this case) requiring detailed information surrounding *exactly* what states ought be pushed/popped to/from the attribute stack during an `glPushAttrib` or `glPopAttrib` method invocation.

My question is: does 'current drawing buffer(s)' entail the `GL_DEPTH_TEST` and `GL_STENCIL_TEST` states in this regard, and where may I find additional information detailing *precisely* what states make up respective attribute bits?

Comment: In case of doubt I you should always consult the standard specification. Not some book. Not the manpages. For OpenGL-1.3 the specification is https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec13.pdf

Comment: You're right, of course. Up until now I've primarily consulted the OpenGL SC specification (OpenGL SC is derived from OpenGL 1.3), which is defined relative to the OpenGL 1.3 spec. As such I merely searched the OpenGL 1.3 specification for the symbolic constant names, the underlines of which my .pdf reader (for some reason) does not understand and may not find. The states and their corresponding attribute bits are documented under Chapter 6: State and State Requests. I'll be sure to add an answer to my original question.

Comment: Woah, I suddenly feel a few good years younger :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GL_DEPTH_TEST` OpenGL state variable is pushed to the attribute stack when `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` or the `GL_ENABLE_BIT` is passed to the `glPushAttrib` function.
Meanwhile, the `GL_STENCIL_TEST` state is saved to the stack using the `GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT` or `GL_ENABLE_BIT` symbolic constants.

As such, neither `GL_DEPTH_TEST` nor the `GL_STENCIL_TEST` state variables are denoted to be written to the attribute stack when `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` is given to `glPushAttrib`.
Furthermore, additional states and their corresponding attribute bits are detailed in chapter 6: State and State Requests of the [OpenGL 1.3 specification](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~uffe/glspec13.pdf):

[image]